# Critique my uneasy proof for the following problem

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $R(z)=\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$ be a complex rational function on $\mathbb{C}-\{P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_n\}$ with $\{P_1, \ldots, P_n\}$ the zeros of $Q(z)$ and not the zeros of $P(z)$. Let $f(z)$ be holomorphic on $U \equiv \mathbb{C}-\{P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_n\}$ such that $|f(z)| \leq |R(z)|$ on $U$. Then $f(z)=CR(z)$ on $U$ for some constant $C$.

Proof. Let $P_k$ be a zero of $Q(z)$ and consider $g(z) \equiv \frac{f(z)}{R(z)}$ on $U_k \equiv D(P_k, r) - \{P_k\}$ where $0<r < \min \{|P_k-P_j|: j \neq k$}. Then $g(z)$ is holomorphic on $U_k$ as it is a quotient of holomorphic functions on $U_k$, $|g(z)|$ is bounded by 1, and the bounded function $g^{*}(z) \equiv \lim_{z \to P_k}g(z)$ at $P_k$ and $g(z)$ on $U$ is holomorphic on $U_k \cup \{P_k\}$ by Theorem 4.1.1., Green and Krantz. By extension $g^*(z)$ is holomorphic on $U \cup \{P_k\}$.

WLOG extend $g^*(z)$ to a holomorphic function on all of $C$. Since $g^*(z)$ is a bounded entire function, then it is constant. Restricted to $U$, $g^*(z)=\frac{f(z)}{R(z)}=C$ for some complex $C$ and so $f(z)=CR(z)$ on U. $\space \square$

This feels too easy and sloppy, but I don't know how to fix it, or even if I need to fix it. Critiques are appreciated!

Comment: I think the proof is ok, you use the fact that if an holomorphic function is bounded around a singularity, then this one you can eliminate, and obtain an holomorphic funtion on the whole domain. I just have a question about the definition of the $P_i$'s: don't you think you have to include zeros of $Q$ which are zeros of $P$, but with less multiplicity?

Comment: The explicit statement on the problem is that P and Q have "no zeros in common."

Comment: Ok, i think my statement would be a little bit more general, but it changes nothing at your proof.

Comment: If we're picky, and for homework we probably should be, you also need to consider the zeros of $R$ (which are the zeros of $P$), since you can't just divide by $0$ in $g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{R(z)}$.